# Python multiprocessing/threading takes longer than single processing on a virtual machine

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm at work on a virtual machine which sits in my company's mainframe.

I have 4 cores assigned to work with so I'm trying to get into parallel processing of my Python code. I'm not familiar with it yet and I'm running into really unexpected behaviour, namely that multiprocessing/threading takes longer than single processing. I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong or if the problem comes from my virtual machine.

Here's an example:

```
import multiprocessing as mg
import threading
import math
import random
import time

NUM = 4

def benchmark():
  for i in range(1000000):
    math.exp(random.random())

threads = []
random.seed()

print "Linear Processing:"
time0 = time.time()
for i in range(NUM):
  benchmark()
print time.time()-time0

print "Threading:"
for P in range(NUM):
  threads.append(threading.Thread(target=benchmark))
time0 = time.time()
for t in threads:
  t.start()
for t in threads:
  t.join()
print time.time()-time0

threads = []
print "Multiprocessing:"
for i in range(NUM):
  threads.append(mg.Process(target=benchmark))
time0 = time.time()
for t in threads:
  t.start()
for t in threads:
  t.join()
print time.time()-time0
```

The result from this is like this:

```
Linear Processing:
1.125
Threading:
4.56699991226
Multiprocessing:
3.79200005531
```

Linear processing is the fastest here which is the opposite of what I want and expected.
I'm unsure about how the join statements should be executed, so I also did the example with the joins like this:

```
for t in threads:
  t.start()
  t.join()
```

Now this leads to output like this:

```
Linear Processing:
1.11500000954
Threading:
1.15300011635
Multiprocessing:
9.58800005913
```

Now threading is almost as fast as single processing, while multiprocessing is even slower.

When observing processor load in the task manager the individual load of the four virtual cores never rises over 30% even while doing the multiprocessing, so I'm suspecting a configurational problem here.

I want to know if I'm doing the benchmarking correctly and if that behaviour is really as strange as I think it is.

Comment: Threading is slower due to the fact two threads cannot execute in parallel, but rather concurrently, due to the GIL in Python. Multiprocessing is slower because of the time it takes to fork the new process. If you had more expensive calculations and spawned less processes (say 2 or 3, depending on CPU cores), multiprocessing would yield faster results.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Indeed I could create a case where multiprocessing is faster than linear.

Comment: What virtualization technology is used? Maybe there are some resource limits that apply to your VM, or your 4 virtual CPUs don't really translate to 4 real HW CPU cores... With `NUM` less than the real CPU count you should usually see better performance for CPU bound problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, firstly, you're not doing anything wrong, and when I run your example on my Macbook Pro, with cPython 2.7.12, I get:

```
$ python test.py
Linear Processing:
0.733351945877
Threading:
1.20692706108
Multiprocessing:
0.256340026855
```

However, the difference becomes more apparent when I change:

```
for i in range(1000000):
```

To:

```
for i in range(100000000):
```

The difference is much more noticeable:

```
Linear Processing:
77.5861060619
Threading:
153.572453976
Multiprocessing:
33.5992660522
```

Now why is *threading* consistently slower? Because of the Global Interpreter Lock. The only thing the `threading` module is good for is waiting on I/O. Your `multiprocessing` example is the correct way to do this.

So, in your original example, where `Linear Processing` was the fastest, I would blame this on the overhead of starting processes. When you're doing a small amount of work, it may often be the case that it takes more time to start 4 processes and wait for them to finish, than to just do the work synchronously in a single process. Use a larger workload to benchmark more realistically.

Comment: Could you move "Linear Processing" into the code block? I tried editing myself, but it said I need to edit more characters, but this is already a great post.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that, done! Thanks for the kind words :)